# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue even though I've set up the settings.py correctly?

Tags: django, cors

amateur developer here. Trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2RJXTtCn2Y&t=1316s), where in the settings.py I have

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:8080']
```

as per the video.

However, when I try to access the server from my front-end, I get the error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/engine' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Appreciate there are many similar posts on SO, but I couldn't understand why I'm having this issue whereas the guy who made the tutorial does not. This is the rest of my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Engine(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime(2024,1,1))
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Engine

class EngineSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Engine
        fields = ('id', 'date')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Engine
from .serializers import EngineSerializer

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class EngineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Engine.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EngineSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from backend_app.views import EngineViewSet

from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('engine', EngineViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

'http://localhost:8080' and 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' are not the same. They may point to exactly the same code and functions, but they are different for such matter.

Put both options inside the list:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:8080', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000']
```

I'm not sure about ports, though.

Some more help is to found [HERE](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/django-cors-guide/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It didn't work, but I'm still trying out other solutions, will post as soon as I find something that works for me.